# Storing the result of a random number in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

I am drawing a surface composed of rigid "molecules" composed of three spheres each. I want to add some randomness to the surface. I have created this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
  \foreach \i in {11,10,...,0}{
    \foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{
      \def\dx{rand*0.1}
      \def\dy{rand*0.1}
      \shade[ball color=red]  (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-0.9}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-1.8}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

judging by the resulting surface, the `\dx` and `\dy` are generated each time they are accessed and not once in each loop. Is there a way to store them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can store the results using `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro>}{<expression>}`. Note that the the argument to functions like `sin(<arg>)` should be given in degrees by default. If not, you should use the "`r` operator". For more on parsing mathematical expressions, read section **63 Syntax for mathematical expressions** (p 527 onward) in the [`tikz`/`pgf` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

I've modified you code snippet into an MWE and used (`\xcoor`,`\ycoor`) to represent the coordinate pair, since they were basically the same for the three shaded balls.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,11}{
    \foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xcoor}{\i+rand*0.1}% x-coordinate
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoor}{0.5*\j+rand*0.1+.4*sin(\i*360/12)}% y-coordinate
      \shade[ball color=red]  (\xcoor,\ycoor) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\xcoor,\ycoor-0.9) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\xcoor,\ycoor-1.8) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. While at it, do you know why I have to multiply the sin argument by 10 to get the wave?

Comment: @Yotam: I've updated my answer. The argument of `sin` has to be an angle in degrees. If you want to specify it in radians, you need to use the `r` operator.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I can't re-select your answer.